# Angular - mock Promise method for Jasmine unit test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, mocking, karma-jasmine

### Method to test

```
  public onSubmit(registerData: RegisterDataModel): void {
    this.registrationService.registerWithEmailAndPassword(registerData).then((msg: string[]) =>
      this.router.navigate(['/completeSignUp']).then(() => {
        msg.forEach(singleMessage => this.notificationService.primary(singleMessage));
      }))
      .catch((msg) => msg.forEach(singleMessage => {
        this.notificationService.danger(singleMessage);
      }));
  }
```

I want to test if `router.navigate` is called in my method. Now I want to mock my  `service.registerWithEmailAndPasswort` Promise but somehow I cannot mock it.

### My Spec File

```
//Stubs
const routerStub: Router = jasmine.createSpyObj('Router', ['navigate']);
const registryStub: RegistrationService = jasmine.createSpyObj('RegistrationService', ['registerWithEmailAndPassword']);
```

## Unit test

```
  it('should navigate on promise - success', () => {
    (<jasmine.Spy>registryStub.registerWithEmailAndPassword).and.callThrough();
    const spy = (<jasmine.Spy>routerStub.navigate);
    component.onSubmit({username: null, email: null, password: null, passwordConfirm: null, termsAndCondition: null});
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/completeSignUp']);
  });
```

The Error that is appearing is: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`
Does anyone how to proper mock this service?

### Edit

I have also tried to mock the promise like:

```
    (<jasmine.Spy>registryStub.registerWithEmailAndPassword)
  .and.returnValue(new Promise(() => Promise.resolve()));
```

But it still throws me:

```
Expected spy Router.navigate to have been called with [ [ '/completeSignUp' ] ] but it was never called.
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As silicon Soul mentioned you need definately mock the `router.navigate` promise with a returnvalue as otherwise it will ent into a `Promise.reject()`. By adding `(<jasmine.Spy>routerStub.navigate).and.returnValue(Promise.resolve());` the unit test should be ok.
The final unit test should look like:

```
  it('should navigate on promise - success', fakeAsync(() => {
    const spy = (<jasmine.Spy>routerStub.navigate).and.returnValue(Promise.resolve());
    (<jasmine.Spy>registryStub.registerWithEmailAndPassword).and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(['test']));
    component.onSubmit({username: 'test', email: 'test', password: 'test', passwordConfirm: 'test', termsAndCondition: true});

    tick();
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/completeSignUp']);
  }));
```

Answer (score 2):

You will get the error because the registerWithEmailAndPassword spy does not return a Promise. You could use callFake to return a Promise:

```
(<jasmine.Spy>registryStub.registerWithEmailAndPassword).and.callFake(() => Promise.resolve([]));
```

Also, promises are asynchronous so you should probably use [fakeAsync](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/fakeAsync) test and tick, or timeout or return an object with *then* method instead of a Promise.

Comment: first of all thanks for the reply, but the registerWithEmailAndPassword does indeed return a Promise the method in the service (I guess is for the question irrelevant, but however) looks as follows:   `public registerWithEmailAndPassword(register: RegisterDataModel): Promise<void | string[]> {
    const successMessages: string[] = [];
    const errorMessages: string[] = [];
    return new Promise<void | string[]>(((resolve, reject) => {
      this.createUserWithEmailCredentials(register, successMessages, resolve, errorMessages, reject);
    }));
  }`

Comment: OK, but you are not calling the original method. You are calling the stub method which returns nothing by default. Using returnValue should also work, but as mentioned previously the promises are asynchronous so you should wait  or force a tick.

Comment: Do u actually have some code to provide? I tried it as u mentioned it with fakeAsync  `it('should call navigate', fakeAsync(() => {
    const spy = (<jasmine.Spy>routerStub.navigate).and.stub();
    (<jasmine.Spy>registryStub.registerWithEmailAndPassword).and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(() => ['test']));
    component.onSubmit({username: 'test', email: 'test', password: 'test', passwordConfirm: 'test', termsAndCondition: true});

    tick();
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/completeSignUp']);
  }))` But i get a: msg.forEach is not a function error... This unit test is a pain..

Comment: :) Sorry can't provide anything tested without the entire code. The fakeAsync code seems fine. I assume that you are getting the error because the Promise catch callback is called and the parameter is not an array. A few things that I noticed. Promise.resolve should be passed the value - Promise.resolve(['test']).  Didn't see any code to mock the result of router.navigate method which will result in error because of the then call. Also, verify that the notificationService does not throw an error.